# JavaScript : Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript

There is an error in my code.

```
function checkWrong()
{
  var programInfo = {};
  var bookedQueue = new programInfo();

  bookedQueue.title = "cost";
  bookedQueue.startTime = "13:50";

  console.log(bookedQueue.title);
}
```

> JavaScript : Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Above error occurs on the 6th line. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: programInfo is **not** a function, is it?

Comment: Yeah, I want programInfo to use just an Object. And I am using Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `new` with objects, only with functions. For more information, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.

So either do:

```
var programInfo = {};
programInfo.title = "cost";
```

or:

```
var programInfo = function () {
    // If you want, you can set default properties here, like:
    // this.title = 'default title';
};

var bookedQueue = new programInfo();

bookedQueue.title = "cost";
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I'm pretty sure you wanted this:

```
function checkWrong() {
    var programInfo = function () {};
    var bookedQueue = new programInfo();

    bookedQueue.title = "cost";
    bookedQueue.startTime = "13:50";

    console.log(bookedQueue.title);
}
```

Comment: Note: @jgillich's answer is more complete than mine.